# Is there an option in Visual Studio 2019 to put the cursor on the nearest character or whitespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am currently working on a C# project and whenever I press the left mouse button, the cursor will go there even if there is no whitespace. This seems to only happen for certain languages for me though.

Here is a screenshot of what I am describing:

[image: Click here to see it]

In the screenshot, whitespace is being shown by blue dots. As you can see, even though there is no whitespace at the cursor, it is still there. In Visual Studio Code, however, this does not happen:

[image: In This picture, the cursor goes as far back as possible when I click]

I was wondering if there was an option to make it like that in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your issue but are you asking how to switch it from selecting & replacing a character to going in between the characters? If so press INS (insert) on your keyboard; otherwise I'm not too sure what you're saying.

Comment: Check out the editor preference for C#... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-formatting?view=vs-2019

Comment: There is "Enable virtual space" option in Options/Text Editor/C#

Comment: Happy coding @CrustyPablo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- Tools

  - Options

    - Text Editor

      - All Languages

        - General

          - Enable Virtual Space *(clear the check box)*

Or, you can change it on a language by language basis (by selecting a language rather than `All Languages`)

I can remember getting that setting set once, it drove me crazy till I finally found the magic setting.